Using a DataTemplateSelector with a ContentTemplate (no xaml)
On a Page, I can use a ControlTemplate to populate the Page's Content.
In this example there are 2 choices for content based on an arbitrary variable, bleDevice, being null or not...
internal void SetContentViewBindingContext(BleDevice bleDevice)
{
    BindingContext = bleDevice;

    var controlTemplate = new ControlTemplate(() =>
    {
        if (bleDevice is null)
            return new NoDeviceDataTemplate().LoadTemplate.Invoke();
        else
            return new BleDeviceDiagnosticItemDataTemplate().LoadTemplate.Invoke();
    });

    _contentView = new() { ControlTemplate = controlTemplate };
    Content = (View)_contentView.ControlTemplate.LoadTemplate();
}

This works fine... And perhaps my understanding of a DataTemplateSelector is wrong, but I would like to use a DataTemplateSelector as it seems to me a more elegant way to select the page's content dynamically.  But I can't figure out how to do so.
Fwiw, here is what I've tried that doesn't work, for probably obvious reasons I'm not aware:
ControlTemplate ct = new(new DeviceDetailsDataTemplateSelector().LoadTemplate);
_contentView = new() { ControlTemplate = ct };
Content = (View)_contentView.ControlTemplate.LoadTemplate();

Any advice?

Do you use a ListView or CollectionView? Is bleDevice a Property of the item?

From the doc, A DataTemplateSelector can be used to choose a DataTemplate at runtime based on the value of a data-bound property. Do you have any data bound property for the page

@LiqunShen-MSFT  added a bit more context.  This is just a method of the Page class.
Yes the this bleDevice is basically the View Model for the View.  This is why what does work, works...

@LiqunShen-MSFT also, i am not using or trying to populate a CollectionView nor ListView, im trying to populate the Content of the Page itself (ie Content = loading from the ControlTemplate)

DataTemplateSelector is not applicable here as it works based on a data-bound property. and usually works for collections.

Yes Collections certainly need a way to bind and dynamically select a view layout.
Only i am sort of doing the same thing within "collection" of pages... albiet a small collection of pages... Ill just need to build this sort of view selection on my own i suppose.

Not quite understand. How do you create the "collection" of pages?

@LiqunShen-MSFT  its a custom collection of pages.  Regardless, I can see the point of view it is not necessary in this situation.

A common usage scenario for a DataTemplate is displaying data from a collection of objects in a ListView, CollectionView or CarouselView. And the DataTemplate is set to the ListView.ItemTemplate property.

A DataTemplateSelector can be used to choose a DataTemplate at runtime
based on the value of a data-bound property. This enables multiple
data templates to be applied to the same type of object, to choose
their appearance at runtime.

The most common scenarios to use DataTemplateSelector is for ListView, CollectionView or CarouselView. A DataTemplateSelector is used to choose a DataTemplate at runtime based on the value of a data-bound property. If you see the official sample, you may find the OnSelectTemplate method in DataTemplateSelector return a DataTemplate instead of a ControlTemplate.
So it may not applicable for this case.
Hope it helps!
